# How to use a mapbox view in a fragment with android studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Good evening,

as asked in the title, I would like to implement a basic mapbox view in a fragment within another fragment. I have been trying to use the android mapbox support fragment example on the website :

i have followed all the steps but I keep getting this error:

```
[Shader]: Vertex shader fill failed to compile: precision highp float;
                                                                  #ifdef GL_ES
                                                                  precision highp float;
                                                                  #else
                                                                  #define lowp
                                                                  #define mediump
                                                                  #define highp
                                                                  #endif

                                                                  attribute vec2 a_pos;

                                                                  uniform mat4 u_matrix;

                                                                  void main() {
                                                                      gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
                                                                  }
```

I am also using genymotion to emulate it, would that play a role in the error?

PS using the 4.1.1 mapboxsdk

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [this Genymotion](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5939) error. We are looking for a fix for this and you can track the progress in that ticket. For now my recommendation would be to test on a physical device if available.